# Marker Clusterer Plus remove cluster on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, markerspiderfier

i'm using this tool

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/

for clustering markers that are in the exact spot or very close (`gridSize: 5`)

What I want to do is to remove a cluster (not all, just one) on click and spiderfy markers with

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Can this be done?

In reference of Marker clusterer I didn't find any function/method that removes a particular cluster.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use my own version of MarkerClustererPlus with a small modification:

```
//@150 of MarkerClustererPlus: modify to send cClusterIcon.div_ on the click event
google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_, cClusterIcon.div_);
```

And in your code use it like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'click', function (cluster, clusterIcon) {
    clusterIcon.remove();
    //Do the other stuff with the markers ...
    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
});
```

Comment: around line 150 on MarkerClustererPlus

Comment: Sorry, found it, I was looking in wrong file (MarkerClusterer, not MarkerClustererPlus). I'll try now.

Comment: Ok, this works (removes/hides icon), but how to show markers that where /are clustered

Comment: cluster.getMarkers();

Comment: With cluster.getMarkers(), i get Markers form that cluster, but they are not shown on map, and I cant fire click event on them (that would triger spiderfy).

Comment: they are not shown because they were clustered, you will have to add them again (without adding them to the clusterer), this will require a good testing and handling of the markers, but now that you can remove the clicked cluster and get its markers I think you'll be able to figure it out in your particular scenario

Comment: I'll definitely try. Thx m8.